# Form field values not being passed to PHP file

Tags: php, jquery, html, ajax, phpmailer

So im making an email form and, using AJAX, link to an external PHP file that uses PHPMailer to send the email. So I have this code in the top of the PHP:

```
if(count($_POST) > 0){

    $message=
    'Full Name: '.$_POST['name'].'<br />
    Email:  '.$_POST['email'].'<br />
    Message: '.$_POST['textarea'].'<br />
    Current Website: '.$_POST['website'].'<br />
    Business Name: '.$_POST['business'].'<br />
    ';
```

and,

- In localhost using wamp, this would work fine and would send the email with the respective fields
- In a live version, the email doesn't go through with the `if(count($_POST) > 0)` in the PHP file
- If the if statement is removed, it does send the email, and I do recieve it, but the email simply has "Full Name:" and "Email:" and so on filled with blanks and no values inputted from the HTML form. Here is the AJAX code:

  ```
  var ajax = {
      isSubmiting: false,
      send: function() {

          if(ajax.isSubmiting == false) {
              ajax.isSubmiting = true;

              var name = $("input[name=name]").val();
              var email = $("input[name=email]").val();
              var textarea = $("textarea").val();
              var business = $("input[name=business]").val();
              var website = $("input[name=website]").val();

                  ajax.SetText("Sending...");
                  $.post("sendmail.php", {
                      name: name, email: email, textarea: textarea, business: business, website: website
                  }, function(data) {
                      if (data.trim() == "true") {

                          ajax.SetText("Sent!");  
                          console.log(data);


                          $.get("sent.html", function(sentData){

                              $("#content").html(sentData);

                          });

                      } else {
                          ajax.SetText("Send mail");
                          console.log(data);
                          $.get("unsent.html", function(sentData){

                              $("#content").html(sentData);

                          });


                      }

                      ajax.isSubmiting = false;
                  });

          }
          else alert("You can only send one email at a time!");
      },
      SetText: function(text) {
          $("input[type=button]").val(text);
      }
  }
  ```

and this is the form HTML markup:

```
<form name="contact-form" method="post" id="contact-form">

                        <h3> We want to hear from you! Tell us about your business and/or project and what you need and we'll get back to you as soon as possible! </h3>

                            <div class="form-group">

                                <label for="name">Your Name:</label>
                                <input type="text" name="name" class="form-control" placeholder="Your Name" required/>

                            </div>

                            <div class="form-group">

                                <label for="email">Your Email:</label>
                                <input type="email" name="email" class="form-control" placeholder="Your Name" required/>

                            </div>
                            <div class="form-group">

                                <label for="web">Current Website (if available):</label>
                                <input type="text" name="website" class="form-control" placeholder="Current Website (if available)"/>

                            </div>

                            <div class="form-group">

                                <label for="web">Business Name (if available):</label>
                                <input type="text" name="business" class="form-control" placeholder="Business Name (if available)"/>

                            </div>

                            <div class="form-group">

                                <label for="comment">Message:</label>
                                <textarea id="textarea" rows="5" class="form-control" name="textarea" placeholder="Message"></textarea>

                            </div>

                            <div class="row" align="center" id="button-row2">

                                <input type="button" value="Submit" onClick="ajax.send()" class="btn">

                            </div>

                    </form>
```

Any idea why this may be happening?

Comment: Can you confirm that in both cases (testing and live) your AJAX code is being run rather than the form begin submitted as an html form to the URL of the same page on which it's located?

Comment: Also, can you confirm whether or not the variables `name, email, textarea, etc.` are populated before being sent in the live environment?

Comment: @fvgs Im sure the AJAX is being run because after $.post where it says if data ==  true, it returns as else. This, i'm guessing, means it went through it first. And I entered values for each of the variables but how can I confirm?

Comment: Is it supposed to be ajax.isSubmitting (with two **t**s)?

Comment: After extracting the values via `var name = $("input[name=name]").val();`, etc. print out the value of one of those variables and see whether or not it's blank. You can also check whether or not jQuery is accessible in your live environment

Comment: In inspected with firebug and all the values went through the "POST" process but no return.

Comment: Could you be more specific with what you mean by "all the values went through" and "no return"?

Comment: As in the data was passed via AJAX to the PHP file but the php file didnt pick it up. When i inspected it, it said "name" along with what I typed in, as well as the other fields.

Answer (score 0):

jQuery is not correctly accessible in your live environment. Therefore,

```
var name = $("input[name=name]").val();
var email = $("input[name=email]").val();
var textarea = $("textarea").val();
var business = $("input[name=business]").val();
var website = $("input[name=website]").val();
```

are all `undefined`

Comment: So how do I fix that?

Comment: This is just a theory; you need to confirm whether or not this is the case as described in one of my above comments

Comment: Ok so in PHP before `if(count($_POST) > 0)` i echoed all the values and i saw them in the console. Also, in local it works perfectly. But on live, its as if once it approaches the `if(count($_POST) > 0)` it just ignored everything under it

Comment: A good diagnostic step might be to determine whether or not any values exist in `$_POST` in the PHP script when it is run in the live environment as a result of your AJAX call. Currently, your description of that case is unclear to me